# TabNavigator with a modal popup with react-navigation? (like Instagram)

Tags: react-navigation

Is it possible to have a `TabNavigator` with a tab bar button that launched a modal screen? Basically mimic the behavior of Instagram's center "Share" button.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are clear with the concepts of react-redux. You can use it to achieve this task. On the click of the tab perform an action that will set/unset the props that you can use to show/hide the modal.

Your reducer for this will be like,

```
case SET_MODAL_VISIBILITY:
     state = {
        ...state,
        modalVisible: !state.modalVisible,
     }
```

the above case will set/unset the modalVisible prop which can be used in a component that is exported with connect keyword of react-redux.

Than your modal will be like

```
 <Modal
     visible={this.props.modalVisible}
     onRequestClose={() => //any function you want to call}
     //any other attributes you want to use
 >
     <View>
          //any view you want to give your modal to
     </View>
 <Modal/>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with `react-navigation`? I'm looking for a way to use that library to create this, and launch the modal from one of the tabs in the `TavNavigator` component.

Comment: Yes for that you need to recognize the navigation action that is performed in your app ..Check this link out https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/redux

Comment: I have redux integrated. And then what? How do I dispatch an action when a tab is pressed? `TabNavigator` presents tabs based on screens you define, I don't see any documented way to attach an onPress handler to do something besides navigate to a screen.